# Is it possible to replace windows search with another software like Agent ransack?

Tags: windows-search, file-search

For example in Explorer,  the search uses Windows Search under the hood to display the results. Is there a way to have it use a different search like X1 or Masterseeker instead and display the results in Explorer?

Comment: Have you done any research regarding this before asking? Have you tried anything?

Comment: You can disable Windows Search, and you can install other tools, but they won't be integrated in Explorer (other than context menu) nor Start.

Comment: Too bad, it's the integration I'm looking for. Just like you can choose your own browser,  I wish there was a way to choose your own search as well.

Comment: The browser runs in its own window, it does not replace or supplant anything else on the system. Setting  a default browser works because the OS sends instructions/info to the browser via standard protocols (URLs mostly). The search UI elements are hard-coded and only talk, via internal communication means, with the underlying search system. Windows has no method to "pass along" search requests to alternate tools the way URLs can be sent to different programs.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **No**, not in the built-in File Explorer's search bar or window. You need to replace the entire program, like by running Agent Ransack to begin with.

---

Some software has integrations that make it easier, like adding context menu entries in file explorer, or this feature where it opens Agent Ransack instead when you press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>:

[image: configuration settings > shell integration]